# Outlook 2011 fails to rebuild database and won't start in OS X

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

I installed Outlook 2011 a while back and never used it.  Since then I created a new Mac user profile and tried running Outlook.  I also had to do a restore from a Time Machine backup.

Now when I try to use Outlook it wants me to rebuild the database but fails when I try.

I don't need to save any email but just want to get Outlook to run.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when I tried to uninstall Outlook I did not do it correctly.  It is a manual process to uninstall Office 2011 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768

Once I followed the steps in the article I worked fine.